# ArcCatalog won't close/exit normally, toolbars disappear instead or it crashes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, arccatalog, serious-application-error

I've had this problem since v10.2 of ArcGIS Desktop, I recently upgraded to 10.3 and it still exists. The problem is that ArcCatalog cannot be closed normally. If I try to close it using the Windows close button (red X in Windows 7), instead of closing, all my toolbars disappear, including the menu toolbar. If I try to close it using File > Exit or by pressing Alt-F4, it crashes with the message:

> ArcGIS for Desktop has encountered a serious application error and is
>   unable to continue.

On the bright side, at least that closes the program. This problem doesn't affect ArcMap.

So if I use the Close button in ArcCatalog, I go from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

The only way to close the program at that point is to kill the process in Task Manager or crash it using Alt-F4. Has anyone else had this problem and solved it? The only info I could find about it online concerned an issue in ArcGIS that was fixed in v10.1 SP1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being my [Xtools](https://xtools.pro/en/overview/) extension, I was using an older version and while the tools still worked with ArcGIS 10.2/10.3, it caused this problem. Updating to an ArcGIS 10.3-compatible version of the extension solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that your Normal.gxt has become corrupted and that you should consider deleting it (after making a backup copy first).

This is described in a very old Technical Article: [Corrupted Normal.gxt file generates 'FATAL ERROR'](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/18729).

There is useful information about this under [Changing your application's appearance back to the factory settings](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00v000000014000000):

> Configuration changes are saved in template documents; for example,
>   ArcMap keeps its changes in Normal.mxt. If you radically change an
>   application and later decide you would like to reset it to its
>   original settings, delete the application's Normal template file. Upon
>   startup, the desktop applications will regenerate their Normal
>   template if they are missing.
>
> **Removing your Normal template**
>
> The Normal templates—Normal.mxt (ArcMap), Normal.gxt (ArcCatalog),
>   Normal.3dt (ArcGlobe), and Normal.sxt (ArcScene)—are located in your
>   user settings folder. For example, in Windows 2000 or XP, the ArcMap
>   Normal.mxt can be found in C:\Documents and
>   Settings\\Application Data\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcMap\Templates,
>   and in Windows Vista, it can be found in
>   C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcMap\Templates.

On my laptop the Normal.gxt is found at

> C:\Users\my_username\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog

which is a little odd because I have ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop installed ... but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work. It looks like the problem may be with my Xtools extension, it's out of date and apparently can cause a similar problem.